# Combining :nth-of-type() and :not

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a strange case of trying to combine two pseudoclasses: `:not` and `:nth-of-type()` to get rainbow striping on non-hidden items

Having a `:not([selector]):nth-of-type([rule])`, I assumed css would filter the `:not` items first before applying the `:nth-of-type` rule, but having them in any order gives me the same result.

Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/j7hjU/

Am I perhaps overlooking something when doing these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I assumed css wouuld filter the :not items first before applying the :nth-of-type

Nope. CSS is fully declarative; every selector is a simple condition that is true or false independently of any selector part. It's not a procedural language where you take a set and process it, narrowing it down with each step. A selector language with procedural rules would be immune to many kinds of optimisation and would be slower.

So `nth-of-type` is only about position within an element's parent, and not position in a 'results list so far' because CSS selectors have no such concept. A selector engine could  look up the test for `nth-of-type` before narrowing it with `not`, as the rules do not interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a duplicate of this question: [Css coloring table problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054891/css-coloring-table-problem)

The answer of that was essentially, no, but you could apply a class to the visible rows to make it work.

Answer (score -2):

CSS parses right-to-left. Have you tried flip-flopping the `:not` and `:nth-of-type`?

[Why do browsers match CSS selectors from right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left)

Comment: Yes I did, but got the same result.

Comment: This is irrelevant. The order of simple selectors doesn't matter.