# How do I apply odd/even styles to elements while taking into account excluded classes?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I apply specific css styling to every (for the sake of argument) odd element in a set of elements, while taking into account a set of excluded elements?

The issue is replicated here (shown in a codepen):

http://codepen.io/houdmont/pen/VLOBBG

A series of elements which have a class `.foo` applied:

```
<a href="#" class="foo">1. Blue</a>
<a href="#" class="foo">2. Green</a>
<a href="#" class="foo">3. Blue</a>
<a href="#" class="foo bar">4. Hidden (blue)</a>
<a href="#" class="foo bar">5. Hidden (blue)</a>
<a href="#" class="foo bar">6. Hidden (blue)</a>
<a href="#" class="foo">7. Green</a>
```

When the `.bar` class is applied, the element is hidden.

I'd like the **remaining** elements with `.foo` applied to be styled odd/even.

Attempt as follows:

```
.bar {
    display: none;
}

/**
 * This clearly doesn't work as I'd hoped it would.
 */
.foo:not(.bar):nth-of-type(even) {
    color: green;
}
```

Ideally, I'd like the seventh element to be green, even though it's an "odd" element, if I were able to exclude the elements with class `.bar` then it would be the fourth element and therefore considered "even", setting the color to green.

Is this possible with CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not possible. Previously answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12205844/1590962

> CSS is fully declarative; every selector is a simple condition that is true or false independently of any selector part. It's not a procedural language where you take a set and process it, narrowing it down with each step. A selector language with procedural rules would be immune to many kinds of optimisation and would be slower.
>
> So nth-of-type is only about position within an element's parent, and not position in a 'results list so far' because CSS selectors have no such concept. A selector engine could look up the test for nth-of-type before narrowing it with not, as the rules do not interfere with each other.

Comment: Happy to accept that as the answer, thank you. Also found that CSS4 selectors will address this issue: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/sneak-peek-future-selectors-level-4/#tree-structural-pseudo-classes-nth-match-nth-last-match

Comment: If a question was previously answered elsewhere, you should flag the question as a duplicate instead. This saves you the trouble of having to copy the answer over and link back to it.

Comment: I will do that next time! (I couldn't find the flag button earlier...)

Answer (score 0):

As Hephistocles said, there isn't any way to do this with only css. On other hand, with javascript it's very simple:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
var x=0;
for(i=0;i<list.length; i++){
    if(x%2==1) list[i].style.color='green';
    if(list[i].className.indexOf("bar")==-1) x++;
}
```