# Selecting first-child after selecting element with not selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am facing one issue. In which I want to select all the folders element that are not having class 'test' and after that I want to skip the first-child (in the result of all the elements that are not having class test).
I created one fiddle [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/LxLx9u6a/)

In which I am trying to set the background color for all the folder element that doesn't have test class and its not a first-child also.

So I first I tried setting background color for all the element that are not having test class.

```
folder:not(.test) {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

And then I added this CSS for skipping first-child element's background color that doesn't have test class.

```
folder:not(.test):first-child{
  background-color:initial;
}
```

But this does not work!!!. In the fiddle only last 3 row should have background color as yellow. But currently 4th row is also having yellow background.
 Any help will be much appreciated.

Note : I am looking for CSS only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the general sibling selector (`~`) for this purpose. This selector would select all `folder` elements that do not have the `class='test'` and also have atleast one previous sibling of the same type. Since it needs to have atleast one previous sibling that is `folder:not(.test)`, the first `folder` element that doesn't have `class='test'` will not be selected.

```
folder:not(.test) ~ folder:not(.test) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```css
folder:not(.test) ~ folder:not(.test) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<folder class="test">
  1.)This is test folder
</folder><br>
<folder class="test">
  2.)this is test folder
</folder><br>
<folder class="test">
  3.)this is test folder
</folder><br>
<folder>
  4.)first:level: this is not test folder
</folder><br>
<folder>
  5.)This is not test folder
</folder><br>
<folder>
  6.)This is not test folder
</folder><br>
<folder>
  7.)This is not test folder
</folder><br>
```

---

The following selector will select only the element that is the ***first child*** of its parent when that element also satisfies the other two conditions - that is, the element type is `folder` and  `class` is not `test`.

```
folder:not(.test):first-child
```

In your code the first child (all  elements here are children of `body` as there is no other container tag) is an element that has `class='test'` and so the ***above selector does not match any element***.

Comment: Sounds great Harry!. I am somewhat new to css3.
Bdw I edited the fiddle now the text are coming inside <p> tags.
I also manipulated the css. But that just don't work.
This is my updated fiddle 
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/ewvuzxg0/)

Comment: @BharatSewani: Just use `folder:not(.test) ~ folder:not(.test) p` like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ewvuzxg0/1/). When you do it this way you are selecting the `p` element which is the child of a `folder:not(.test)` element that has a previous sibling of same type. But when you do `folder:not(.test) p ~ folder:not(.test) p`, it will try to select a `p` element which is the child of `folder:not(.test)` which in turn is a sibling of a `p` element (see the order in the selector). Our `folder` is not a sibling of any `p` and so no element is colored in your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks man!!! but I was little worried when I have to skip first two  or more elements. Is that possible?

Comment: @BharatSewani: You can't keep changing the question. I think your original question is answered and so you should mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the hollow tick mark and ask a separate question if you have a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Bharat,

CSS is declarative and non procedural, then you can't combine "not" and "first-child" (or "nth-of-type").
More information here :
[Combining :nth-of-type() and :not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205664/combining-nth-of-type-and-not)

But you can easily use tilde "~"
https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators

> The general sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~)
>   character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
>   elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the
>   document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the
>   second one.

You should try :

```
folder:not(.test) ~ folder:not(.test) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Orb